# Repeating an operation (similar to screw)

Tags: modeling

In 3DSmax (I forget the name but I'd know it if you saw it) you can define a (simple - as in TRS only) procedure that will be repeated n times. Like screw.

Suppose I wanted to extrude and slightly scale down, extrude and slightly scale down, rather than doing it 15 times say, I could just use this?

How can I do something similar?

(If the scalar is < 1 then it will form a curve shape)

Actually it'd make more sense just to attach a cone. So this question is two fold, how may I glue faces from a different shape together, and is there a more general version of screw? (In 3dsMax is was a dialog with a table full of input boxes)

Comment: Found ctrl J for join, but not sure how I can join between the two. Was called "bridge" in 3dsMax

Comment: I've found it here http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Edges#Bridge_Edge_Loops but what is "mesh->edges"

Comment: Have you tried the Screw modifier?

Comment: @cegaton yes, where's this mesh menu? (I like the docs, but they don't tell you where the menus they use are!)

Comment: Also @cegaton is there a way to set the resolution of a primitive, like (sorry to use 3dsmax again) in 3dsmax you would just change the x/y segments, the cone has far too many for what I need!

Comment: Hi, this site works best when you ask one question at a time. I would say 'how to glue faces' is a separate question.

Comment: @RayMairlot the question is really "where is this menu I found in the documentation" and together there'd be loads of tiny little questions that'd just be annoying. It is called bridge and the menu is in Mesh (at the bottom, above the timeline) edges BTW

Comment: Please do keep it fo one question, so that there can be one clear answer. Please re-edit your question and make separate posts for each other. You can ask up to 50 questions in a month!

Comment: This is the task of joining say a tail to a body. @cegaton if that helps, a tail tapers and I want a fast way to do it.

Comment: Also It would help if you add examples of the functions you are looking for.

Comment: For quick repeat of one action you can also use Shift+R. It will repeat only the last asction you did.

Answer (score 3):

You can always resort to <kbd>F3</kbd> to view the history and repeat *extrude region and move* alternating with *resize*. it will always extrude the same distance and resize the same percentage relative to the size of the face that's been extruded.

<kbd>F3</kbd> > *extrude region and move*, <kbd>F3</kbd> > *resize* **and repeat**.

[image]